# Union two queries and flag duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates, union

I have two tables. One has all options and one has the user selected options as well as some they created which may not be in the options table.

I need to union the data so I get back a result set which includes all of the options, as well as the users options and somehow flag which are user only and which overlap with the main options data...

Example...

**OPTIONS**

```
`COLOR`   | `ANIMAL`
---------------------
RED       | DOG
BLUE      | DOG
GREEN     | DOG
YELLOW    | CAT
PINK      | CAT
ORANGE    | CAT
```

**USER SELECTED OPTIONS**

```
`COLOR` | `ANIMAL`
------------------
GREEN   | SNAKE
BLUE    | DOG
PINK    | CAT
PURPLE  | CAT
```

**My results need to look like...**

```
`COLOR` | `ANIMAL`| `DUPLICATE_OR_NEW`
----------------------------------------
RED     | DOG     | 0
BLUE    | DOG     | 1
GREEN   | DOG     | 0
YELLOW  | CAT     | 0
PINK    | CAT     | 1
ORANGE  | CAT     | 0
PURPLE  | CAT     | 1
GREEN   | SNAKE   | 1
```

The sort order does not matter in this scenario. I was trying with UNIONS but I think I need to do it by joining the two tables together. I am not coming up with a solution so far.

Comment: But what are the queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be called cheating but it will work

```
SELECT COLOR, ANIMAL, sum(DUPLICATE_OR_NEW)
FROM
(
SELECT COLOR, ANIMAL, 1 as DUPLICATE_OR_NEW FROM options
UNION ALL
SELECT COLOR, ANIMAL, 2 as DUPLICATE_OR_NEW FROM UserSelection
) as UTable
GROUP BY  COLOR, ANIMAL

-- 1 = unchosen option
-- 2 = new user added option
-- 3 = option exsisted chosen by user
```

see SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01c79/2

Comment: I love cheating if it works. Your answer got is about 95% of the way there. Because of the minus 1 the items from my table 2 which do not exist in table one display a zero. The easy fix was to change the SELECT COLOR, ANIMAL, '1' as DUPLICATE_OR_NEW FROM table_name2 **** to SELECT COLOR, ANIMAL, '2' as DUPLICATE_OR_NEW FROM table_name2. This put a 2 in the column for the items that overlapped and left a 1 for the new items. That is fine for my use because I can just say where greater than zero. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this:

```
select color, animal, 1 as duplicate_or_new
from UserSelected
union all
select color, animal, 0 as duplicate_or_new
from options o
where not exists (select 1 from UserSelected us where us.color = o.color and us.animal = o.animal)
```

The correct way to do it with the `union all`/group by:

```
 select color, animal, max(which) as duplicate_or_new
 from (select color, animal, 1 as which
       from UserSelected
       union all
       select color, animal, 0 as which
       from options
      ) t
group by color, animal
```

The following query creates two separate flags:

```
 select color, animal, max(isUser) as IsUser, max(isOption) as IsOption
 from (select color, animal, 1 as IsUser, 0 as IsOption
       from UserSelected
       union all
       select color, animal, 0 as IsUser, 1 as IsOption
       from options
      ) t
group by color, animal
```

You can put them in a case statement to format the information:

```
(case when max(isUser) = 1 and max(isOption) = 1 then 'both'
      when max(isUser) = 1 then 'user'
      when max(isOption) = 1 then 'option'
      else 'impossible'
 end)
```

Comment: How could you tell if the options is completely "new" or was selected from the existing list ?